# mysql - how to set a value to result of query and optimize 

Tags: php, mysql

```
table a: id, name
query :SELECT * FROM a
result: list value id, name
```

i want add a age = 18 to all record and do it with query not manipulate result

```
ex: SELECT a.*, age = 18 FROM a
```

How to do ?

Thanks

**Addition question:**

Could use WHERE clause on value that i have just set.

```
SELECT ex.title , ex.age
  ( SELECT a.title, 18 as age FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.title, 19 as age FROM b) as EX
WHERE age = 19
```

Maybe it will be slowed ? any better solution?

Comment: If you just want to return 18 in the age field for all values you should use something like "SELECT a.*, 18 as `Age` FROM a", although might be better to be done outside mysql?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.*, 18 age FROM a
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job

```
 Select a.*, 18 as age from a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in result, you can use the following query

```
select a.*, 18 as age from a
```

If you need to update records in your db, you ahve to use `Update`

```
update a set age=18
```

Comment: the a table has not age field